# Rails, Invalid Foreign Key in Devise::RegistrationsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

**The Error:**

PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_03de2dc08c" on table "comments" DETAIL: Key (id)=(6) is still referenced from table "comments". : DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1

```
def exec_no_cache(sql, name, binds)
  type_casted_binds = binds.map { |attr| type_cast(attr.value_for_database) }
  log(sql, name, binds) { @connection.async_exec(sql, type_casted_binds) } [HIGHLIGHTING THIS LINE]
end

def exec_cache(sql, name, binds)
```

What is going on:

So I am new to ruby and rails, just making an app to learn from--I am using Devise for users, and whenever I try to edit the user profile on my app it will either

A.) Work fine

or

B.) Break with this error.

(Typically on an alternating cycle where it will break, if I then reload the page and proceed again it will work.  Then if I try to edit the user again it will break, and the cycle continues)

**The terminal:**

(Actions taken: Loading the home page -> Loading the edit user page -> Submitting the edit (I didn't change any value) -> ERROR -> Click to go back, loading the edit page -> Submitting the edit (I didn't change any value) -> Worked.)

```
Kegans-MacBook-Pro:MyApp Kegan$ rails s
Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated.
Please use a String or nil.
An Array ({"GEM_PATH"=>["/Users/Kegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1", "/Users/Kegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global"]}) was passed in from bin/rails:3:in `load'
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.rc1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:05 -0600
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Link Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links" ORDER BY "links"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links" ORDER BY "links"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 8], ["votable_type", "Link"], ["vote_flag", true]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 8], ["votable_type", "Link"], ["vote_flag", false]]
  Forum Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "forums".* FROM "forums" ORDER BY "forums"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "forums".* FROM "forums" ORDER BY "forums"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (84.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 291ms (Views: 263.2ms | ActiveRecord: 16.4ms)


Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:05 -0600
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:05 -0600
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] Registered connection (Z2lkOi8va29ob3JkL1VzZXIvNg)
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] RoomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] RoomChannel is streaming from room_channel
Started GET "/users/edit" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:10 -0600
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] Changing the sanitized parameters through "Devise::ParameterSanitizer#for(sign_up) is deprecated and it will be removed from Devise 4.2.
Please use the `permit` method:

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
    # Your block here.
  end
 (called from configure_permitted_parameters at /Users/Kegan/Documents/AppDev/myApp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10)
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] Changing the sanitized parameters through "Devise::ParameterSanitizer#for(account_update) is deprecated and it will be removed from Devise 4.2.
Please use the `permit` method:

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user|
    # Your block here.
  end
 (called from configure_permitted_parameters at /Users/Kegan/Documents/AppDev/MyApp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11)
  Rendering devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (14.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 77.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started DELETE "/users" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:18 -0600
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9Ou51KmxWKW+SheDAZl86Rtb8jMQBDSVZswiwfkHxUpg2b4DA/9xneXzPXsckQ7V6oy6MqBkWPctS24X1Z9V7w==", "user"=>{"avatar"=>"", "name"=>"Joshua Artos", "email"=>"joshgamer1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "bio"=>"Josh. Kick ass at video games.", "location"=>"Fort Collins", "age"=>"18", "gender"=>"Doesn't Matter", "interestedin"=>"Netfix", "major"=>"Doesn't Matter", "twitterurl"=>"", "instagramurl"=>"", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] Changing the sanitized parameters through "Devise::ParameterSanitizer#for(sign_up) is deprecated and it will be removed from Devise 4.2.
Please use the `permit` method:

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
    # Your block here.
  end
 (called from configure_permitted_parameters at /Users/Kegan/Documents/AppDev/MyApp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10)
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] Changing the sanitized parameters through "Devise::ParameterSanitizer#for(account_update) is deprecated and it will be removed from Devise 4.2.
Please use the `permit` method:

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user|
    # Your block here.
  end
 (called from configure_permitted_parameters at /Users/Kegan/Documents/MyApp/Kohord/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.3ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)



ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_03de2dc08c" on table "comments"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) is still referenced from table "comments".
: DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1):

activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `exec_no_cache'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:587:in `execute_and_clear'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:116:in `exec_delete'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:140:in `delete'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `delete'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/relation.rb:543:in `delete_all'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:525:in `destroy_row'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:141:in `destroy_row'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:115:in `destroy_row'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:184:in `destroy'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:283:in `block in destroy'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:283:in `destroy'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:314:in `block in destroy'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:314:in `destroy'
devise (4.1.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:66:in `destroy'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:181:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:31:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/digestor.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (6.5ms)
  Rendering /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendering /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/KingKegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (52.5ms)
```

(Deleted some rendering for character limit mitigation)

```
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:18 -0600
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] RoomChannel stopped streaming from room_channel
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:21 -0600
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:21 -0600
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] Registered connection (Z2lkOi8va29ob3JkL1VzZXIvNg)
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] RoomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] RoomChannel is streaming from room_channel
Started PUT "/users" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:28 -0600
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MfnKmUW4Xfct9NyjC9bbwfEDusLvTYXHQRuqyltHr1yly81O7/Z0z3ZN9lsW3qn9ANTyw18t6aUKnOYcd98/+Q==", "user"=>{"avatar"=>"", "name"=>"Joshua Artos", "email"=>"joshgamer1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "bio"=>"Josh. Kick ass at video games.", "location"=>"Fort Collins", "age"=>"18", "gender"=>"Doesn't Matter", "interestedin"=>"Netfix", "major"=>"Doesn't Matter", "twitterurl"=>"", "instagramurl"=>"", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] Changing the sanitized parameters through "Devise::ParameterSanitizer#for(sign_up) is deprecated and it will be removed from Devise 4.2.
Please use the `permit` method:

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
    # Your block here.
  end
 (called from configure_permitted_parameters at /Users/Kegan/Documents/AppDev/MyApp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10)
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] Changing the sanitized parameters through "Devise::ParameterSanitizer#for(account_update) is deprecated and it will be removed from Devise 4.2.
Please use the `permit` method:

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user|
    # Your block here.
  end
 (called from configure_permitted_parameters at /Users/Kegan/Documents/AppDev/MyApp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 94ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:28 -0600
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Link Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links" ORDER BY "links"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links" ORDER BY "links"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 8], ["votable_type", "Link"], ["vote_flag", true]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 8], ["votable_type", "Link"], ["vote_flag", false]]
  Forum Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "forums".* FROM "forums" ORDER BY "forums"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "forums".* FROM "forums" ORDER BY "forums"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 51.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)


[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:28 -0600
[ActionCable] [joshgamer1@gmail.com] RoomChannel stopped streaming from room_channel
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:28 -0600
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-06-10 14:15:28 -0600
```

**Some Code:**

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :forums
  has_many :links
  has_many :discussions
  has_many :comments

  has_many :chats
  has_many :chatrooms, through: :chats




# It returns the articles whose titles contain one or more words that form the query
  def self.search(query)
    # where(:title, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
    where("name like ?", "%#{query}%") 
  end


  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missingMike.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

User Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def index

    if params[:search]
      @users = User.search(params[:search])
      @users = @users.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    else
      @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
    end
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_links = @user.links
    @user_comments = @user.comments 
    @user_forums = @user.forums 
    @user_discussions = @user.discussions 

  end

  def goAnonymous
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.anonymous = true
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def leaveAnonymous
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.anonymous = false
    redirect_to :back
  end

end
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :current_password, :avatar, :bio, :gender, :location, :interestedin, :major, :age, :instagramurl, :twitterurl, :anonymous) }
  end

end
```

/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<h2 class="foldersBox">Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>


  <div class="foldersBox card-wrap">
    <div>

      <div>

        <div id="label">
          <%= f.label :avatar %>
          <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", :autocomplete => "off" %>
        </div>


        <br>

        <h4>Fun Stuff:</h4>

        <div>
          Bio: (At least try to be funny)<br>
          <%= f.text_area :bio, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          Location:<br>
          <%= f.text_field :location, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          Age: (Most likely the brief time frame when you won't lie about your age (21-24))br>
          <%= f.select :age, (18..99), class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          Gender (Whatever is PC right now):<br>
          <%= f.text_field :gender, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          Interested In:<br>
          <%= f.text_area :interestedin, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          Major: (Like you won't change in a semester, probably just leave blank)<br>
          <%= f.text_area :major, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>


        <h4>Social Media Stuff</h4>

        <div>
          Twitter:<br>
          @<%= f.text_field :twitterurl, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          Instagram:<br>
          @<%= f.text_field :instagramurl, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>






        <div>
          <strong><%= f.label :current_password, class: "currentPasswordForm" %></strong> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i>
          <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.submit "Update", class: "updateBTN" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br><br>

    <br><i>
    Cancel my account<br>
    Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: {
      confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %>
    </i>

  </div>
</div>
```

Migration for Comments:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :link_id
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :comments, :link_id
  end
end
```

Model for Comments:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :link
end
```

Comment: Can you show comment model and the migratoin file for it?

Comment: Added them. Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 1):

If you rollback your DB to just before that migration (db:rollback or db:migrate:down VERSION= the number part of your migration filename.)

Change your migration at the end to reference link and not just link_id. re run your migrations:

From

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :link_id
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
  end
    add_index :comments, :link_id
 end
end
```

to

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :link, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
  end
    add_index :comments
 end
end
```

To do this with migrations you would do the following:

```
rails g migration RemoveLink_IdFromComments

def change
  remove_column :comments, :link_id
end

rails g migration AddLinkToComments

def change
  add_reference :comments, :link, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but how would I go about doing so?  I'm about 17 migrations past the CreateComments

Comment: Well you will have to generate a new migration to remove the old field and add the reference.

Comment: Have updated to reflect the migrations at the bottom

Comment: How did you go with this @Kegan where you able to get it working?

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the help. Sorry for the late response, I was away from my computer this weekend.  I had to reset my database after making these changes in order for the app to work, and I still get the same error: "PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_03de2dc08c" on table "comments" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "comments". : DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1"

Comment: What throws me is how it works the second time through...?

Comment: And this is when you are updating a record? with the changes to the link_id to a reference?

Comment: If you are removing the user when this happens let me know as it could need dependant: :destroy on comments under your user.
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

Comment: Nothing gets removed, and nothing should be removed. This all comes from editing the profile as any user would, and this is even when no inputs/user info (or all) have been changed.

Comment: I added the full edit view. The character limit had been full, so I deleted some rendering lines in the terminal output.

Comment: After trying it on Safari, when editing the profile I get after submitting changes... "Bye! Your account has been successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon."

Comment: Hey Kegan I just noticed that your error relates to your destroy action on your devise controller?! can you please check your routes for devise?
Devise::RegistrationsController#destroy

Show your route file if possible

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. Tried to delete a user. PG raised an exception on a post.
The problem was i deleted a user with id=3. But there were posts in the database with a user_id of 3.

Adding `dependent: :destroy` to the association fixed it for me. It will delete all the user's posts when the user is deleted.

Try:

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `belongs_to :link` is causing the issue. I think you need to get rid of it and add link reference to your table again and try.

```
rails g migration RemoveLinkIdFromComments link_id:integer
rails g migration AddLinkRefToComments link:references
#Do check your newly created migration files it everything is correct.
```

Run rake db:migrate and try again. Let me know if that solves your issue.

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_03de2dc08c" on table "comments"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) is still referenced from table "comments".
```

If we look at the errors, we can see we have a wrong association.
Can you delete everything from your development database(all the data) and try again.

Comment: Didn't fix anything, in fact now it broke more.  I can't view any user profile now:   "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"links", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"  even though I did a db:rollback of the two migrations you suggested -- and if I try to add another migration adding link_id it says it already exists.